# TLS error codes in as3crypto

Tags: flash, apache-flex, as3crypto

I am using TLSSocket (part of [as3crypto](http://code.google.com/p/as3crypto/)).  Every now and then I see this in my console:

> GOT ALERT! type=51

and then the socket will close.  It appears that this is the error handling in [TLSEngine.parseAlert](http://code.google.com/p/as3crypto/source/browse/trunk/as3crypto/src/com/hurlant/crypto/tls/TLSEngine.as).

The trouble is, I don't know what the TLS error codes are.  Has anyone seen this error before?  If not, where can I find documentation on the TLS error codes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a fatal "decrypt error".

See the wikipedia article on TLS: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security#Alert_protocol

Answer (score 0):

Decrypt error, means that this side 's calculated encryption code doesn't equal to the side's calculated encryption code, reasons may vary.